# How to ignore or remove null element from an array inside collection

Tags: php, laravel

```
Collection {#363 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Tag {#376 ▶}
    1 => null
    2 => Tag {#374 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I want to remove the second key/pair element from this collection. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Or have a look at [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `$collection->filter();` to remove the null values.

```
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value != null;
});
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter).

Comment: No need to add a callback when filtering null values. Doing `$filtered = $collection->filter()` will work as well.

Comment: this returns empty array []

Answer (score 12):

Additionally, `Collection@filter` will remove the `null`s without having to use any closure to do the checking. Similar to how `array_filter` will remove the `null`s.

```
$filtered = $collection->filter();
// nulls will be removed
```

To supplement the previous answer using `Collection@filter`

Comment: This does not remove `null` entries, it removes entries that are loosely equivalent to `false`, eg: `[], 0, false, '', null` will all be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As you're dealing with an array of strings, you can simply use array_filter(), which conveniently handles all this for you:

```
print_r(array_filter($linksArray));
```

Keep in mind that if no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed. So if you need to preserve elements that are i.e. exact string '0', you will need a custom callback:

```
// PHP < 5.3
print_r(array_filter($linksArray, create_function('$value', 'return $value !== "";')));

// PHP 5.3 and later
print_r(array_filter($linksArray, function($value) { return $value !== ''; }));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly remove only NULL values and not zeros(0) from collection.
Ex: [10,10,0,9,null]

```
$filtered = $collection->filter(function($value, $key) {
            return !is_null($value);
        });
```

Output: [10,10,0,10]

As other people say, you can use just filter() method without callback to remove values that are equivalent to FALSE ([], 0, NULL, FALSE, '')

official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter

Answer (score 1):

Use [filter](http://%20https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter) method to remove nullable values and after use [values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values) method to reset the array keys (if necessary).

`$collectionFiltered = $collection->filter()->values();`

Comment: This does not remove `null` entries, it removes entries that are loosely equivalent to `false`, eg: `[], 0, false, '', null` will all be removed.